# Developer tool athat allows me to generate grafical presentation of my Smart Contracts

Tags: truffle, tools

I remember there was a tool, **maybe** even a `truffle npm package`. That would generate a file that you could open and see a graphical presentation of your smart Contracts (Similar to database schemes). It would show which contract is calling another one etc.

But for the life of me I cant remember its name, nor am I able to find it online.
I am 100% sure it exists because I used it a year back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found it!! Really useful thing.

https://medium.com/@kccmeky/how-to-create-uml-class-diagram-from-your-solidity-contract-6bc050016da8

Answer (score 1):

You can install the VS Code extension `Solidity Visual Developer` by tintinweb, then `npm install -g surya` on VS Code. After that, hit `CONTROL + SHIFT + P` and find surya to visualize the call graph.

Comment: Thanks, that too is an interesting tool!